# Dynamic pop-up on jquery .hover function within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have a for-each loop inside my table, which is structure as below:

```
<c:set var="count" value="0" />
<c:forEach items="${message }" var="element">
    <div id="env">
        Details - <b>${fn:toUpperCase(element.key)}</b>
    </div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
        class="display dataTable" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Env</td>
                <td align="center">URL</td>
                <td>Details</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${element.value}" var="details"  varStatus="loop">
            <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>${details.env}</td>
                    <td><a href="${details.url}" target="_blank">${details.url}</a></td>                        
                    <td><a href="#" class="trigger">Details</a></td>
                    <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                    <div class="pop-up">
                        <h3>Pop-up div Successfully Displayed</h3>
                        <p>
                          ${details.env}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to display a pop-up for each element of the loop when the user hovers over a  element by using jquery. My jquery code is:

```
$(function() {
    var moveLeft = -200;
    var moveDown = 10;
    $('a.trigger').hover(function(e) {
      $('div.pop-up').show();
    }, function() {
      $('div.pop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a.trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
      $('div.pop-up').css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });

  });
```

My problem is, it is only showing for the last element of the loop. How can I show for each element in loop of class '**trigger**'?

Comment: I see this is not pure html, javascript. What language are the elements like <c:forEach , ${details.env} etc?

Comment: @ile I am using this in jsp. ${details.env} is coming from Spring controller.

Comment: I am not experienced with the spring framework, but is it possible to post a sample or link to a live example? It is hard to debug like this and maybe some elements are not assigned the hover property or the 'trigger' class for example.

Comment: it's not a problem with Spring here. I can see the contents in table of my page. Even I can see the pop-up for all href but it shows the content of only last row. I am using [this example](http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/02/create-a-pop-up-div-in-jquery/) in my code.

Comment: well if all of your 'a' elements have 'trigger' class and there are no errors in the console - the jquery selector and function is perfectly ok. The two functions inside right after each other are something new to me and unless you are certain this is legitimate - perhaps you should rework it, see my suggestions below.

Comment: yes, these two functions work perfectly fine even within forEach loop. I cannot get elements of respective loop in that particular pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems suspicious:

```
 $('a.trigger').hover(function(e) {
      $('div.pop-up').show();
    }, function() {
      $('div.pop-up').hide();
    });
```

The two function next to each other seem dubious. Did you mean to do something like:

```
 $(function(){
    $('a.trigger').hover(function() {
        $('div.pop-up').hide();
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    });
    $('a.trigger').mousemove(function() {
        $('div.pop-up').hide();
    });
  });
```

In this example - you hide all pop ups and show the one after the current element. The downside on my suggestion is that you need to maintain the  structure. It would be more consistent if for example you used unique ids/classes for the groups.

**UPDATE**

I see two possible problems.

1 The pop-up divs are not inside  elements and may be removed by the browser. See in the below fiddle the first div doesn't have a td and if you inspect the html source - it simply isn't there.

2 The hover/mouse movement also seems amphibious, I rewrote it more simply with a **mouseover** and **mouseleave** (note I added an additional td parent for the popup divs):

```
$(function () {
    $('a.trigger').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().children().show();
    });
    $('a.trigger').mouseleave(function () {
        $('div.pop-up').hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/n6wh2/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: Without loop it is working but this code will not hide once pop-up is displayed. Within loop it's not working at all.

Comment: @Zahed see my revised answer, does this help? (naturally keep you loop in order to assign all elements correctly)

Comment: @Zahed I prepared a working fiddle to illustrate an ok example. If this doesn't help you, please provide more information, otherwise its really hard to diagnose the possible issue.

Comment: @Zahed how about the last updated example, did it work ok for you too? Please upvote/accept the answer if so.

Comment: This was already working without loop & yes above also works but when I tried using this inside my for:each loop it was unsuccessful :(
I have removed this from my code & using a pop-up instead. Thanks a lot for your help ile! :)

Comment: @Zahed '*This was already working without loop*' - I don't think so, because **1.** There is no <td> wrapper on the div and **2.** The mouse hover function is broken. [Proof here](http://jsfiddle.net/n6wh2/4/) There may be other issues arising from spring of course, but your html and javascript definitely needed fixing.